# Science stack exchanges helping other science stack exchanges!

Tags: discussion

The Physics Meta promotes support for all Science sites on Stack Exchange, in [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) post. The same meta post is now on several other science SE Meta sites.

Open Data SE is one of the sites that has benefited from this (and is currently still benefiting from this, if you look at the "Sites in Beta" section of that Meta post).

Let's give back to the younger science communities, now that we here at Open Data SE have graduated out of the Commitment stage, and let's help some of the other sites in Beta, as they are doing for us.

Below is the post from the Physics Meta (now on several others too).

Comment: sorry, i get what you are trying to do, but is this a question?

Comment: @albert It is not a question. In the illest form, you can call it an "advertisement", which was started on the Physics Meta page 8 years ago, and is now also on Chemistry Meta, Computational Science Meta, Math Educators Meta, Astronomy Engineering Meta, Robotics Meta, Space Meta, etc.   Most of these have generally been well received with upvotes on their Meta pages. OpenData has been advertised there for many years, so while we here can certainly downvote and close this "question", it would seem unfair when OpenData has benefited from it for so many years on other Meta sites.

Comment: i'm just confused. so where does these need to go? no one said anything about downvoting or closing. again, i am simply confused. i can't speak for everyone but very sure that most people here do/would support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Science proposals need your help! Consider committing to these, to make them successful & scientific:

See also the long list of [science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=progress) and [technology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=progress) proposals on Area 51.

---

## Committers needed

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Synthetic Biology]

---

## Site definition needed

---

## Sites in beta

[Science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science?tab=beta) and [technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=beta) sites currently in beta include:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Materials Modeling]
[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Operations Research]
[image: Astronomy]
[image: Earth Science]
[image: Engineering]
[image: Mathematics Educators]
[image: Open Data]
[image]

---

This is community wiki -- feel free to add other proposals worth mentioning.

Comment: Removed HSM because of [this](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/325/8052) (you will need enough rep to see it though, since it's deleted).

Comment: Also, while you're on a roll, you might consider to add it in these places!! https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32548/190792